# SPACE key issue on send_keys method in chromium-driver on Raspberry Pi

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, chromium, raspbian

Using:
Raspberry Pi 4
Raspbian
chromium-driver 72.0.3626.122-1~deb9u1
selenium 3.141.0

When using ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.SPACE) my Chromium Browser mystically gets something like Keys.ENTER and does not countinue to write into input field but sends this form to server like it is complete.

This issue does not depend on website. Checked about 10 ones.

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.py contains line:
SPACE = '\ue00d'

Answer (score 0):

I used JS instead:

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('login_email').value='12345'")